# Hook to return true when the_post() is used in a custom while loop

Tags: query-posts

I fetch external data like this, but I also added the_post();

```
while($slice = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
    the_post();
    rest of my stuff
}
```

I need a hook to tell me if the_post() returns true, something like this:

```
while($slice = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
    the_post();
    if(the post returs true){ do something;
    else { rest of my stuff }
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: what are you trying to determine exactly? the_post doesn't return anything.

Answer (score 0):

if you use the native [**`wp_query`**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) to select posts instead of custom sql queries you can check against the `have_posts()` method of `wp_query`